# Write a function in a cell, function is dependent on 'RF(x,t)', and 'RF' dependent on 'x', without putting RF function in the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

firstly for context, I have to calculate a life table. I have a sequence of x values from say 1 to 100(which would be ages all in one column). The mortality at each age is dependent on a reduction factor(RF) which is a function of age x and another variable t(just a secified value).   NOW, I want to calculate the mortality for each x, BUT, I want to store my RF(x,t) in another cell, like creating a function and just calling it from the cell I store  the mortality in, like if I were to use "R" or "Python" etc... I hope this makes sense, is this possible in excel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?